# Convert fully defined control into a style

Tags: wpf, devexpress

How can I transfer a fully defined control into a style?

Imagine I have a complex control like the LinearGaugeControl from DevExpress.
I defined every property to my needs and now I want this to be a style I can use on every used LinearGaugeControl.

Is there a way to do it easy and fast?

```
<dxga:LinearGaugeControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30">
        <dxga:LinearGaugeControl.Scales>
            <dxga:LinearScale MajorIntervalCount="2" MinorIntervalCount="5"
                ShowMajorTickmarks="True"
                ShowMinorTickmarks="True"
                ShowLabels="True"
                Margin="-40,-40,14,-40"
                LayoutMode="BottomToTop">
                <dxga:LinearScale.MajorTickmarkOptions>
                    <dxga:MajorTickmarkOptions Offset="5" />
                </dxga:LinearScale.MajorTickmarkOptions>
                <dxga:LinearScale.MinorTickmarkOptions>
                    <dxga:MinorTickmarkOptions Offset="5" ShowTicksForMajor="True" />
                </dxga:LinearScale.MinorTickmarkOptions>
                <dxga:LinearScale.CustomLabels>
                    <dxga:ScaleCustomLabel Content="500Hz" Offset="-14" Value="-1" Foreground="#FF62D7E7" />
                </dxga:LinearScale.CustomLabels>
                <dxga:LinearScale.LabelOptions>
                    <dxga:LinearScaleLabelOptions Offset="-15" />
                </dxga:LinearScale.LabelOptions>
                <dxga:LinearScale.RangeBars>
                    <dxga:LinearScaleRangeBar Value="60">
                        <dxga:LinearScaleRangeBar.Options>
                            <dxga:LinearScaleRangeBarOptions Offset="0" Thickness="6" ZIndex="150" />
                        </dxga:LinearScaleRangeBar.Options>
                    </dxga:LinearScaleRangeBar>
                </dxga:LinearScale.RangeBars>
            </dxga:LinearScale>
        </dxga:LinearGaugeControl.Scales>
    </dxga:LinearGaugeControl>
```

Comment: Did you try _right click on the control, edit template, edit a copy_? Maybe that´s what your looking for? I´m not sure the template would have all the settings you´ve done so far though. But it might have been better to define a template in the first place...

Comment: @Ben - no the template is just the standard template without the settings I made. Is it better to use a template than a style?

Comment: Well you can pretty much edit the template just to be a style template and don´t touch the content presenters, bindings, etc. at all.